# How to merge 2 different unsigned int in C

Tags: c, int, bit-manipulation, concatenation, unsigned

I'm trying to merge two unsigned ints, which I have in array.
It looks like

```
hex[0] == 0x0A;
hex[1] == 0x2C;
```

I need to merge these two hexadecimal numbers into one, so the result should be `0x2AC`.

I mean in binary it looks like
`01010` and `101100` so the result is `1010101100`.

I think I should use bitwise operators to do this but I have no idea how. 
Thanks.

Comment: You have not shown the type of variable for `hex[]` but whether it is an `int` or a `char` type you can't assign those values in that way. Neither `A` or `2C` are `unsigned int` type, unless there is another variable `A`. Also `==` does not assign a value, it is a comparison test.

Comment: Also not clear what the merging algorithm is.

Comment: As @RaymondChen says, please be very specific in what you mean to accomplish by "merging". It appears that you're maybe trying to sort of concatenate the binary representations of the values based on most-compact "trimmed" binary strings? That can of course be done but I've never heard of doing that, or why it might be useful. If you can say more about the problem you're solving you'll probably get more useful assistance.

Comment: @BenZotto the task is to transform UTF-8 to Unicode. For example CAAC in UTF-8  is 2AC in Unicode. I removed BOMs of the bytes so CA is now A and AC is now 2C. Now I need to concatenate these numbers.

Comment: OK. I'm a little fuzzy about the mechanics of this transformation (and I'm candidly a little unsure that what you're suggesting is necessarily the right way to do it) but you should edit your question above (hit "Edit") to include this information as well as some more detail about what part of the transformation this incorporates. Good luck!

Comment: You are not being clear.  A concatenation of A and 2C would intuitively be A2C or 2CA, but you expect the result 2AC, which suggests inserting the four bit value in `hex[0]` _between_ the two 4 bit halves of hex[1].  If that is what you want, state that clearly; is not, correct your question.  A single example is not a specification and remains ambiguous.

Comment: Oh, this is UTF-8 decoding. There are subtleties in UTF-8 decoding and it's better to use a well-debugged UTF-8 decoder like iconv than trying to write your own.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand precisely what you want, but I assume, you have two unsigned chars, a and b, whose value is

```
a=0xUV;  
b=0xWY;
```

where U, V, W and Y are the 4 bits nibbles that form the these values. And it seems that you want an unsigned short formed of the nibbles UWVY. So in your case U==0, V==A, W==2 and Y==C

This can be done by masking and shifting. Masking with 0x0f extract the lower nibble, while masking with 0xf0 extract the upper one. And it is sufficient to shift them at their proper position n the final result.

This can be done with the following C code

```
unsigned char a=0x0A;
unsigned char b=0x2C;
unsigned short result=  (a&0xf0)<<8) // gives 0x0000
                      | (a&0x0f)<<4) // gives 0x00A0
                      | (b&0xf0)<<4) // gives 0x0200
                      | (b&0x0f);    // gives 0x000C
```